# How to fix "The table was not found. [Multipatches]" error thrown by KMLToLayer tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to run the `KMLToLayer` tool available in ArcGIS Pro within `Python` code chunk inside `RStudio`, but I keep on getting the following errors:

```
The table was not found. [Multipatches]
The table was not found. [Polygons]
Failed to delete raster dataset
Failed to execute (KMLToLayer).
```

The `KMZ` file that I am trying to convert only has `Placemarks` and `Line Paths`, but from the error messages it appears that the tool is also looking for `Polygons` and `Multipatches`. Interestingly, the tool generates the expected `file geodatabase` with both the `point` and `line` feature classes as I had expected, but it keeps on throwing the error messages! I am failing to understand what's going wrong. If anyone in the community experienced similar problems with the tool and were able to sort it out, can you please guide me do the same?

Here is the code that I have used for the conversion:

```py
# r.getwd() is simply a hack to get workspace path with forward slashes on Windows
spatial_path = r.getwd() + "/Results/SpatialFiles"
kmz_file = "StopIntersectionListSortedByDrvFreq.kmz"
arcpy.conversion.KMLToLayer(in_kml_file = spatial_path + "/" + kmz_file,
                            output_folder = spatial_path, 
                            output_data = "StopIntersections")
```

Comment: Does the tool fail or is it just a warning message? If just a warning message you may be able to suppress it.

Comment: @BigGerman, the message says that "something unexpected caused the tool to fail", but as I said, the tool is generating the output. Since the message said that the "tool failed", I was wondering if it didn't produce all pieces of the output that it should have. Please take a look at this image showing the exact messages produced by the tool: https://ibb.co/vLVD9r4
.

Comment: Yeah definitely looks like it is throwing some exception.  If the tool is expecting the those other layers in the kmz I wonder if you could create those in your script before calling KMLToLayer. Otherwise, since it is giving you the expected output, have you tried catching that error and continuing on?